# How to track open, click and bounce stats email sent by aws SendBulkTemplatedEmail as email campaign?

Tags: amazon-sns, amazon-ses

How to track open, click and bounce stats email sent by aws SendBulkTemplatedEmail as email campaign?  I use SNS and notification is received. but not distinguish according campaign.

Comment: Have you considered using configuration set ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-configuration-sets.html

Comment: yes, configuration set is define.  i have a campaign with 5000 emails and i'm send it by BulkTemplatedEmail 1000 email in 1 minutes. bounce notification received on http endpoint but i'm not distinguish bounce email according campaign